# Can't append to dictionary

Tags: python

I have a set of file extensions (.jpg, .png, .exe, etc.) in a set called `set_of_files`.

Below, I populate the keys of a dictionary from this set, while making the values `None`.

The variable `line[2]` contains the file size in bytes for each file extension.

My goal is to append `line[2]` as the value to each file extension in the dictionary, and then add up the total bytes.

i.e. `'.jpg': [1, 3, 4, 5]` ->   `'.jpg': [13]`

However, I'm confused because I can't append to this dictionary (last line).

```
import re

# create set

set_of_files = set(list_of_files)

# populate dict

dicts = {key: None for key in list_of_files}

# go through and place total size by extension name

for line in open(file):

    line = re.split('\s+', line)

    for specific_line in set_of_files:

        if line[3].endswith(specific_line):

            dicts[specific_line].append(line[2])
```

Comment: you want a `collections.defaultdict(list)`

Comment: You can't `append` to `None` - presumably the value should be initialized to `[]`.  (Consider using [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this.)

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Provide samples of all input data and explain how the output does not match the input

Answer (score 0):

You can't append it, because, you've initialised `None` as values for dictionary.

```
import re

# create set

set_of_files = set(list_of_files)

# populate dict
                 _________________________ "None" is assigned here
                |
               \|/
dicts = {key: None for key in list_of_files}

# go through and place total size by extension name

for line in open(file):

    line = re.split('\s+', line)

    for specific_line in set_of_files:

        if line[3].endswith(specific_line):

            dicts[specific_line].append(line[2])
```

Instead, initialise an empty list `[]`, like this...

```py
import re

# create set

set_of_files = set(list_of_files)

# populate dict

dicts = {key: [] for key in list_of_files}

# go through and place total size by extension name

for line in open(file):

    line = re.split('\s+', line)

    for specific_line in set_of_files:

        if line[3].endswith(specific_line):

            dicts[specific_line].append(line[2])
```